# Can surgical spirit and formaldehyde prevent blisters?

Tags: medical-science, safety, sport

I saw the following claim in an [article](http://www.runnersworld.co.uk/beating-injury/qa-why-these-blisters-every-time-i-run/656.html) on Runner's World website:

> If your feet sweat profusely, this can increase the chance of blisters. Try soaking them in surgical spirit, or even better, three per cent formaldehyde solution once a day. This will help reduce the perspiration.

**Is this a valid technique for reducing perspiration in your feet?**

Judging from the Wikipedia entry, I don't think I'd want to put [formaldehyde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formaldehyde#Safety) on my feet, although [surgical spirit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgical_spirit) doesn't sound as dangerous.

Comment: I think the idea here is rubbing alcohol dries out the skin, that's why swimmers put it in their ear when they have water in their ear. Will it stop the formation of perspiration in the long term, that I very much doubt. But you're right, soaking your feet in formaldehyde sounds insanely dangerous.

Comment: I reworded your question to make it more appropriate for skeptics.

Comment: @samIam - The claim is that it will reduce the amount your feet will perspire.  Drying after you are done running is not going to do much for you while you are running.  To be effective it would need to reduce the amount of perspiration released by your feet while you run.